# How to extract digit with leading characters and units of the value?

Tags: r, regex

What's the quickest and easiest way to extract the digits with the leading characters, if exists, and the units, with or without spaces?

```
res <- c("Diam MM = 2.6 cm.","Mild  (<2mm).")

value <- as.numeric(str_extract(res, "[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]+(?=[ ]?(cm|mm)?)"))
```

But I only get: `[1] 2.6  NA`

How can I include `2.6 cm` and `<2mm`?

Comment: Do you need to capture the inequality `<` as well?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Yes. The inequality also has meaning for decision making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using `gsub`:

```
res <- c("Diam MM = 2.6 cm.","Mild  (<2mm).")
gsub(".*?([<>=]*\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\s*\\w+).*", "\\1", res)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using the `stringr` package:

```
res %>%
  str_replace_all(" ", "") %>%
  str_extract("[<>=].+[cm|mm]")
```

Only difference is that this solution keeps the `=`.

But hard to know how well this generalizes to your data without seeing more of it.