# Regex extract word pattern and create column to save the value following the pattern using r?

Tags: r, regex

Previously, I had asked similar question here: 
[How to extract digit with leading characters and units of the value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48247356/how-to-extract-digit-with-leading-characters-and-units-of-the-value/48251141#48251141)

Turned out, the data that they gave me was not original. Somebody had attempted to extract, and gave me the modified data. Now, I finally got the original data which looks like this:

```
test <- c("Normal aortic root.","Normal aortic root. Asc Ao Diam 2D 3.1 cm. "," ","Normal aortic root. The aortic root is normal in size. ","Normal aortic root.","Aorta not well visualized","Normal aortic root.","Aorta not well visualized The aortic root is normal in size. "," ","Normal aortic root. The aortic root is normal in size. Asc Ao Diam 2D 2.6 cm.","Normal aortic root.","Asc Ao Diam 2D 4.1 cm. ","Normal aortic root. The aortic root is normal in size. ","Normal aortic root. The aortic root is normal in size. Asc Ao Diam 2D 2.7 cm.","Aorta not well visualized The aortic root is normal in size. ","","Mild Atheroma (<2mm).","Normal aortic root.","Normal aortic root. The aortic root is normal in size. ","Aorta not well visualized","","Aorta not well visualized","Normal aortic root. The aortic root is normal in size. ","Normal aortic root. The aortic root is normal in size. Asc Ao Diam 2D 3.1 cm.","Normal aortic root. The aortic root is normal in size. ","Asc Ao Diam 2D 2.9 cm. ","","","Normal aortic root. AoR Diam MM = 2.6 cm.","Normal aortic root. Mild Atheroma (<2mm).","","Normal aortic root. The aortic root is normal in size. There is mild ascending aorta dilation. Asc Ao Diam 2D 3.8 cm.","","Normal aortic root. The aortic root is normal in size. Asc Ao Diam 2D 3.3 cm.","Normal aortic root. The aortic root is normal in size. ","There is mild ascending aorta dilation. Asc Ao Diam 2D 4.0 cm. ","The aortic root is normal in size. Asc Ao Diam 2D 2.7 cm.","","Normal aortic root. Asc Ao Diam 2D 3.0 cm. AoR Diam 2D = 2.9 cm. ","Normal aortic root. The aortic root is normal in size. ","Asc Ao Diam 2D 3.3 cm. ","Normal aortic root. The aortic root is normal in size. ","Normal aortic root. The aortic root is normal in size. ","Normal aortic root. The aortic root is normal in size. ","","Normal aortic root. The aortic root is normal in size. Asc Ao Diam 2D 2.8 cm.","Aorta not well visualized","Aorta not well visualized","Normal aortic root.","Normal aortic root. The aortic root is normal in size. ","Normal aortic root. The aortic root is normal in size. ","Normal aortic root. The aortic root is normal in size. ","","The aortic root is normal in size. ","Normal aortic root. The aortic root is normal in size. ","","Normal aortic root. The aortic root is normal in size.")
```

What I need to do is, find the numeric value with the unit. For example `3.1 cm` in the second element of the `test` vector. Then anything that precedes the measurement, with certain words-pattern, should be created as a column of the dataframe, and the value assigned to that column. In some cases, there are two different measurements in the same line like the one in element number `39`. For example:

`Asc Ao Diam 2D 3.1 cm`

`Asc Ao Diam 2D` should be extracted and spaces replaced by "_", and 3.1 cm assigned to the column value.

`AoR Diam 2D = 2.9`

`AoR Diam MM = 2.6 cm.`

or if these patterns do not match, then extract only the first word like for this one in element `30`

```
Atheroma (<2mm).
```

This is one of my several attempts:

```
\s[a-zA-Z]{3,4}\s[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\s[a-zA-Z]{4}\s\w+(?=\s*([<>=]*\d+(?:\.\d+)?[^D]\s*\w+))
```

and I was playing around in https://regexr.com to see if this fetches what i need. Then I was going to code it in `R` to save the columns and values in the data frame for each row.

The data frame contains five other regular columns such as `id`, `age`, `gender`, etc. `test` vector is extracted from one of the columns of the data frame.

The problem I ran into is I couldn't figure out how to extract names if two different names exist in the same line. And, also couldn't figure out how to check the length of the word such that if the given word pattern doesn't match, then single word `Atheroma` as in element `30` should be selected as the column.

**Expected Output**

```
df <- data.frame(id, age, gender, test)
```

for each extracted word pattern, it should be created as column if it doesn't exist in the data frame.

```
df

id  age gender  test    Aor_Diam_2D AoR_Diam_MM Asc_Ao_Diam_2D  Atheroma
1   49  F   "Normal aortic root. Asc Ao Diam 2D 3.0 cm. AoR Diam 2D = 2.9 cm."  2.9 cm  NA  3.0 cm  NA
```

Comment: What's the expected output for the given input?

Comment: @ctwheels, I updated the question.

Comment: your dataframe has only one row?

Comment: No, this is just an example. My data frame contains patient data and is really big. It has about 35 variables and 18000 rows. They're all similar. This is just to show how the extract word should create a column and add value.

Comment: but for entry you need to create new column names .... where should they stored?

Comment: in the same data frame

Answer (score 1):

Here is a try

```
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(id = 1,
                 age = 49,
                 gender = 'F',
                 test = "Normal aortic root. Asc Ao Diam 2D 3.0 cm. AoR Diam 2D = 2.9 cm.")

df$Asc_Ao_Diam_2D = str_replace(str_extract(df$test, 'Asc Ao Diam 2D [0-9]+.[0-9]+ cm'), 'Asc Ao Diam 2D ', '')

df
```

**Update**
Matching on words with specific length and generate the column names accordingly can be done with sth like this

```
num_pattern <- '[0-9]+.[0-9]+ (cm|mm)'
pattern1 <- '[a-zA-Z0-9]{3} [a-zA-Z0-9]{2} [a-zA-Z0-9]{4} [a-zA-Z0-9]{2}'

possible_pattern1_list <- str_extract_all(paste(df$test, collapse = ' '), paste(pattern1, num_pattern, collapse=' '))

possible_pattern1 <- sapply(possible_pattern1_list, function(V) {
  str_extract(V, pattern1)
})

possible_pattern1 <- unique(possible_pattern1)

for (i in 1:length(possible_pattern1)){
  df[,str_replace_all(possible_pattern1[i], ' ', '_')] <- str_replace(str_extract(df$test, paste(possible_pattern1[i], num_pattern, collapse=' ')), possible_pattern1[i], '')
}
```

This is pretty ad-hoc and you would need to first figure out all the possible patterns in the data. If the periods in the example can be used as delimiter, I think the work can be done with much more ease.

Comment: So, this means, I'll need to check 18000 rows and list all the variables to make the column. Isn't there a way to select the column names from the pattern like 3 letter word followed by 2 letter and 4 letter + 2 letter or 3 letter + 4 letter + 2 letter only if the next one followed by is decimal number followed by unit (cm/mm)? select that word and make the column in the dataframe. That's basically what I was looking for.